# P5.js - Is there a way to cut out an image area?

Tags: processing, p5.js

Is there a way to "cut out" a piece of image and use it with the P5.js library?

**Example:** Lets say I have a image of the size 100x100 but need to get a 10x10 pixel cutout that starts at pixel 50,50

[image: 10x10px cutout from an 100x100px image from 50,50px]

I want to take the resulting 10x10 image and place it anywhere with **image(result, X, Y, 10, 10)**.

**Note:**
The only thing I could find online similar to this was using **mask()** but the result is not what I need.

Comment: What about the css `clip` property? `img {
    position: absolute;
    clip: rect(0px,60px,200px,0px);
}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a deeper look inside, and help from fellow P5ers I figured out that the solution is:

**The *GET()* method from P5.js**

https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/get

The get() method can be used as needed: get(startX, startY, width, height) and returns and image that can be saved or used as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use copy() from p5.
[P5 copy() reference](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Image/copy)