# How can I crop an image in p5.js without drawing image on the screen

Tags: javascript, image, crop, p5.js

I've researched and found that you can "crop" an image by using [get()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46574273/p5-js-is-there-a-way-to-cut-out-an-image-area), but the image has to be drawn on the screen where you then take a section of the canvas. Is it possible to load an image then save a cropped version of it in a variable? So maybe something like this:

```
var img;
var cropped;

function preload(){
  img = imageLoad('dog.png', crop)
}

function crop(image){
  cropped = crop(img, 0, 0, img.w/2, img.h) // Getting left half of image 
}
```

Thank you.

---

EDIT:
This is the function I made using copy(), but I don't know if there's an easier way that I'm missing.

```
function crop(image, x, y, w, h) {
  var cropped = createImage(w, h);
  cropped.copy(image, x, y, x + w, y + h, 0, 0, x + w, y + h)
  return cropped;
}
```

Comment: What is this `crop()` function? I'm pretty sure your code will cause a stack overflow.

Comment: It was pseudo code, an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the pixels of an image directly. You don't have to draw it to the canvas first.

Start by reading through the [P5.Image](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Image) reference.

At a high level, what you want to do is create a new graphics (the `createGraphics()` function is your friend, and then draw the section of the image you want to that graphics. Whether you draw the image or the graphics to the canvas is up to you.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to create my own crop function using copy().